# WPF Show dialog Touch Issue

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

In  our pos system we use **WPF**.  We are facing few touch related issues.
Issue is that when we load a child window from  button Touch down event from the Parent window that child window loads fine, but any touch actions performed in child window is mimicked in main window as the child window closes.

E.g  Child window has a close button  in `position X,Y` (in relation to entire screen). When user touches it child window is closing as expected, But a Button in Main window with the position of X,Y gets a focus. This causes a issue when they press enter button or click some other button.

I tries setting the focus for a Textbox which actually should be. but cusror moves to  textbox yet  Button has the touch focus.

Comment: which event you have used for child window's close button?

Comment: TouchDown and PreviewMouseDown

Comment: ' protected void TableGrid_TouchDown(object sender, TouchEventArgs e)
  {
   e.Handled = true;
   if (OnTableClickOrTouch != null)
   {
    TableTouchEventArgs args = new TableTouchEventArgs();
    args.TableSelected = LinkedTable;
    OnTableClickOrTouch.Invoke(this, args);
   }
  }'

Comment: Use MouseDown instead of PreviewMouseDown

Comment: We had to use PreviewMouseDown  as in some cases touch it self not firing.

Comment: See I think that behavior is because of PreviewMouseDown event.

Comment: This bug has existed for years and surprisingly no one reported until now: Please upvote the bug issue so MS team can take a look at it: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/890778/touch-bugissue-with-showdialog-and-textbox.html